# Mongodb client's SCons failed to find libboost_system

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, boost, scons

I've installed boost in `$HOME/local`, and downloaded `mongo-cxx-driver-v2.4` and run `scons --extrapath=$HOME/local`, the output shows

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
```

The content in the `config.log` show the errors:

> cons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread...
>   .sconf_temp/conftest_1.cpp <-
>     |
>     |
>     |
>     |int
>     |main() {
>     |
>     |return 0;
>     |}
>     |
>   g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_1.o -c -O3 -pthread -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -Ibuild -Ibuild/mongo -I/home/jiang/lei/local/include -I/home/jiang/lei/local .sconf_temp/conftest_1.cpp
>   g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_1 -pthread .sconf_temp/conftest_1.o -L/home/jiang/lei/local/lib -L/home/jiang/lei/local/lib64 -lboost_thread
>   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by /home/jiang/lei/local/lib/libboost_thread.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /home/jiang/lei/local/lib/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>   /home/jiang/lei/local/lib/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   scons: Configure: no

I've also tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `$HOME/local` but it did not help.

How could I let Scons correctly find the boost_system.so?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the options:

```
 - --use-system-boost 

 - --libpath
```

That is:

```
scons --full --use-system-boost --sharedclient -j5 --cpppath ${HOME}/include --libpath=${HOME}/lib
```

Comment: I have changed the scons file within the MongoDB client to let it check `boost_system` before checking `boost_filesystem`.